# WTL window/form crashes after infinite message loop causes stack overflow

Tags: visual-c++, wtl

I have a legacy project I need to fix bugs in, WTL/VC++. One of the problems - a crash of the main window (well, the entire application, of course) after Ctrl+X or Ctrl+Z keys are used. I don't have any custom accelerators assigned to those keys.
 I found that the "fatal" key combinations cause an infinite message loop with

`uMsg == 273 (0x00000111)`

that eventually crashes with stack overflow error:

```cpp
 Command Code: 5, ID: 29892, HANDLE:  0xe091aFirst-chance exception at 0x007f88fa 
 in <myApp>.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
 Unhandled exception at 0x007f88fa in <myApp>.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
```

I simply patched it in the message processing function -

BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMDIChildWindowImpl)

```
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CREATE, OnCreate)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_DESTROY, OnDestroy)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CLOSE, OnClose)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_TIMER, OnTimer)
```

*
*

```
    COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_FILE_NEW, OnNewDownload)
    COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_UPLOAD_FOLDER_SET, OnUploadFolderSet)
    COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_OPEN_RECORD_BY_ID, OnOpenOnline)
```

*
*

```
    NOTIFY_CODE_HANDLER(HLN_PORTAL_RECORD_DOWNLOAD, OnPortalPageNotify);
    NOTIFY_CODE_HANDLER(HLN_SELCHANGED, OnWebFormNotify);
    if(uMsg == 273)
     return false;
    else
     CHAIN_MSG_MAP(baseClass)
```

END_MSG_MAP()

But I'm not satisfied with this band-aid patch, it would be nice to understand what's going on - and I actually want those key combinations do the Windows default things on my form, "cut" and "undo"

more info on the fatal messages:

Ctrl+X -

uMsg    273 unsigned int

wParam  123171  unsigned int

lParam  0   long

lParam  0   long

Ctrl+Z -

uMsg    273 unsigned int

wParam  123179  unsigned int

lParam  0   long

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, my VC++ kung fu is rather rusty; If anyone could give me a hint where to look for the ideas, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

O.

Comment: `273` is `WM_COMMAND` and you seem to keep bouncing this command until it fills the stack. Your code snippets above don't show though what exactly is being done wrong.

Comment: I see, WM_COMMAND - so I should be careful to check against wParams as well, not to filter out other menus/accelerators and such. Thanks, I should have been more persistent in finding what the code was. I guess it bounces around because it's not being handled in 'base classes' and gets forwarded back to the 'child' one. As of the code - I really don't know what to post here that would help. Thanks again, Roman!

Comment: Normal flow of operation is that a `COMMAND_ID_HANDLER` or `COMMAND_HANDLER` or whatever handler for `WM_COMMAND` handles the message and it terminates processing there. What you possibly having is that this handler starts some activity which generates the same notification and it rolls on up to stack overflow. Hence, the handler is important. And you also have a call stack with details.

Comment: Brilliant! there was no MESSAGE_HANDLER for WM_COMMAND in this window/class nor in its base ones, and there was a chain-call/redirect message forwarding that caused the infinite loop. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is still a scent of something being unsaid. I'd say you don't need a handler line there, and instead you should rather look for a forwarding line which is placed incorrectly, to complete a circular reference.

Comment: precisely! the line CHAIN_MSG_MAP(baseClass) passes the message to a base class that didn't have a handler for the WM_COMMAND, but what it did have - the CHAIN_ACTIVETABVIEW_COMMANDS macro that was doing the following `::SendMessage(m_hWndActive, uMsg, wParam, lParam)`, that is - sending the message back to the active window, where it all started - hence the infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this, thanks to @Roman R. - in the window in question, there was no handler for the WM_COMMAND message, and in one of its base classes there was a function that generated the infinite loop by forwarding the message back to the active window. So I added this handler -

```
        if(uMsg == WM_COMMAND)
          return DefWindowProc(WM_COMMAND, wParam, lParam);
```

which seems like a good solution for me.

Thanks!